# Setting up Java Enviornmental Variables?

Tags: java, environment-variables

I have set `JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26` in user defined variables and system variables and `classpath = .;` in user defined variables `PATH = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin` in system variables.

Now when I type java on cmd on windows 7 os then am getting message - Error could not open `` `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\i386\jvm.cfg' ``.

Thing to note here is that initially only jre6 was defined in Java folder and so I had to install jdk but still am getting this error any clue?

**Update**
I have able to get java information, all I did was initially I had set up path variable information in following some `%SYSTEM_ROOT%` and other variables in the PATH Variables values but now I just put `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin` as first value in PATH Variables value list and so it worked, guess `%SYSTEM_ROOT%` has pre-defined settings for Path which was pointing to old jre path location.

1. Now when I run `java -version`, I
   get following information, how do i
   know if java installed is 32-bit or
   64-bit?

> java version "1.6.0_26" Java(TM) SE
>   Runtime Environment (build
>   1.6.0_26-b03) Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode,
>   sharing)

Comment: Have you tried to restart cmd?

Comment: yes i did, not sure what is happening in here.

Comment: And have you removed the previous entry of jre in PATH variable?

Comment: C:\Program Files is for 64 bits applications on Windows 7 64bits. Are you using 64bits java on 64bits Windows?

Comment: Am using 32-bit windows 7 os and I want to find what java am using but am not able to print out those values.

Comment: @Serhiy- I have checked PATH Variable again and there I do not have an entry for old jre path.

Comment: If you cd to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin in cmd and type java -version, you should be able to see the version information.

Comment: Does the file exist? Normally, when you install jdk it will ask whether you want to install jre as well. Check if jre and its contents are still there.

Comment: @gigadot-jre contains are there in new jdk as i have installed it with jre contains.

Comment: jre is not present there at all, it has been uninstalled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your path variable is correct but for classpath variable use 
`SET Classpath="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\lib"`

JVM uses class path at run time to search for .class files.

By using ".;" JVM will search for .class files in bin directory whereas the compiled .class files of rt.jar are in lib directory.

This why you're facing errors.

learn more about classpath variable @ http://programmingbulls.com/classpath-variable-java

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your on 32 or 64 bit by reading the "sun.arch.data.model" system property in java;

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model"));
```

Mine answers '64'.

You can view all available system properties with something like this;

```
Properties p = System.getProperties();
Enumeration keys = p.keys();
while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
  String key = (String) keys.nextElement();
  String value = (String) p.get(key);
  System.out.println(key + ": " + value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set path=%path%;"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin"
```

[image: set path=%path%;"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin"]